# Fast way to search through an array of elements

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, find

I have an array of structs and I need to locate all the elements that share a certain condition.

Currently I use:

```cs
Array.FindAll(someArray, x => x.eg == "*Perfomance Test*")
```

But after some googling I noticed that there is a much faster way by using the LINQ `Where`-method.

```
someArray.Where(x => x.eg == "*Perfomance Test*")
```

I did some testing and the results are pretty impressive:

- `FindAll`: *00:00:03.06*
- `Where`: *00:00:00.20*

The problem is that `Where` returns `IEnumerable`. And I call this method that returns all these certain elements from the array within the for loop. Which is the type of loop I need to use. I used the `.ToArray()` method, but that made it much worse so that `FindAll()` is the faster approach.

Because of that it seems to me that if I need to get an array of elements, `Where` is much slower option than `FindAll`. But maybe I'm missing something.

Are there any better, *faster* options?

Comment: Well, try `Where(...).ToArray()` and you'll be surprised.

Comment: `Where` appears to be faster on first sight because it uses deferred execution. It doesn't actually go and find the elements until you called `ToArray`.

Comment: Yeah but after I used .ToArray() performance wise is much worse. Slower than calling FindAll(). FindAll: 00:00:02.92 and Where: 00:00:03.07

Comment: @UnknownUser Yes, that's because `Where` on its own only builds the query; it doesn't actually do the search until you "request" that (using something like `ToArray(), `ToList()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, etc.)

Comment: Now I understand, but are there any better search options? Faster than FindAll or Where().ToArray(). I call this method quite frequently and I'm worried that this might get an impact on performance.

Comment: Well, if you look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,1111) of `FindAll()`, it simply just uses a for loop internally and checks each element against the given condition; that's all. So, I don't really think you can beat that.

Comment: The linked duplicates are, strictly speaking, about `List<T>.FindAll()` rather than `Array.FindAll()` but the same answers apply.